# Optaplanner 8 - School timetabling - assigns first timeslot and room

Tags: spring-boot, optaplanner

I am beginner with optaplanner and tried the springboot application as part of optaplanner documentation however after I followed the exact steps the solution always picks the first timeslot and first room for every lesson.

https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.3.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#springBootJavaQuickStart

Not sure what I am missing - please help. Thanks

Comment: I don't know that example set too well, but this sounds like some constraints being commented-out ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I followed the constraints in the example - https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.3.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#_define_the_constraints_and_calculate_the_score

Comment: Fixed. Thank you, it was to do with constraints. Appreciate your response.